# How do you query by Hibernate polymorphic criteria properties

Tags: hibernate, polymorphism

Assume

```
@Entity 
Class Animals { }

@Entity
@Inheritance( stragegy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
class Dogs extends Animals {
    private String furType;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance( stragegy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
class Cat extends Animals {
    private String furType;
}
```

All entities are real classes in my database and I don't have the option of redesigning our database.

How can I used a DetactedCriteria to create a disjunction query that says give me all "Animals" where furType= 'loud' for dogs OR furType= 'soft' for cats?
Sorry I didn't design the class hierarchy so I'm not responsible for the fact that the property names are the same and I can't redesign it because there are other subclasses who's tables don't contain "furType".

Comment: In JPA 2.0 you've got TYPE(...) construct which might be used to select only particular subclass of your inheritance tree.

Comment: Thanks. Can you expand on that? How should I add disjunction criteria such that I can specify the TYPE(...) in each Criterion?

Answer (score 2):

In JPA 2.0 you can use the `TYPE()` construct to do this job. Something like this (not checked) should work:

```
SELECT a 
  FROM Animals a 
  WHERE (TYPE(a) = Dogs AND a.furType = 'loud') OR 
        (TYPE(a) = Cat AND a.furType = 'soft')
```